# A bug regarding the Auth0 login process in React app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I’m currently using Auth0 React SDK to set up Auth0 in my React app. I’ve encountered an issue with the login process.

**What is the problem?**
After successfully logging in, the app redirects to the home page, but it keeps reloading endlessly, and the address bar displays different values for a query parameter named code.

**What I expected?**
I expected that there was no any bug occurring since the setup process of Auth0 for React in the Auth0 documentation looked clear and easy to understand.

**What are my solutions?**
I tried to make sure that there are not any failed login or failed exchange statuses by checking logs. When I check the ‘Monitoring’ => ‘Logs’ section on the Auth0 Dashboard, I notice numerous entries with ‘success login’ and ‘success exchanges’ statuses.

Since the encoded code value is only available if something is set by the client application in the /authorize request, my suspicion is that the AuthProvider isn’t functioning correctly, causing the isAuthenticated state to always be false and triggering the loginWithRedirect function repeatedly.

**Here is my code**

**Auth0ProviderComponent**

`import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";`
`import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";`

`export const Auth0ProviderWithNavigate = ({ children }) => {`
`const navigate = useNavigate();`

`const domain = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL;`
`const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;`
`const redirectUri = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_FRONTEND_URL;`

`const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {`
`navigate(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);`
`};`

`if (!(domain && clientId && redirectUri)) {`
`return null;`
`}`

`return (`
`<Auth0Provider`
`domain={domain}`
`clientId={clientId}`
`authorizationParams={{`
`redirect_uri: redirectUri,`
`}}`
`onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}`
`>`
`{children}`
`</Auth0Provider>`
`);`
`};`

main component

```
import "./init";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { Auth0ProviderWithNavigate } from "./components/AuthProviderWithNavigate";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Auth0ProviderWithNavigate>
        <App />
      </Auth0ProviderWithNavigate>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

app component

```
import react, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Aos from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

import Layout from "./containers/Layout";
import { UserProfileProvider, type User } from "./contexts/UserProfileContext";
import { LoadingProvider } from "./contexts/LoadingContext";
import { RequestModalProvider } from "./contexts/RequestModalContext";
import { NameModalProvider } from "./contexts/NameModalContext";
import {
  ArticleRequestProvider,
  type ArticleRequest,
} from "./contexts/ArticleRequestsContext";
import RequestModal from "./components/RequestModal";
import NameModal from "./components/NameModal";
import Loader from "./components/Loader";
import { getUserProfile } from "./utils/getUserProfile";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

function App() {
  const {
    user: auth0User,
    isAuthenticated,
    isLoading: isLoadingAuth0,
  } = useAuth0();
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [requestModal, showRequestModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [nameModal, showNameModal] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [articleRequests, setArticleRequests] = useState<ArticleRequest[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoadingAuth0 && isAuthenticated && auth0User) {
      // get user profile
      getUserProfile(auth0User)
        .then((userData) => {
          setUserProfile(userData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("error when setting user profile", error);
          setUserProfile(null);
        });
    }

    Aos.init();
  }, [isLoadingAuth0, isAuthenticated, auth0User]);

  return (
    <UserProfileProvider value={{ userProfile, setUserProfile }}>
      <RequestModalProvider value={{ requestModal, showRequestModal }}>
        <ArticleRequestProvider value={{ articleRequests, setArticleRequests }}>
          <NameModalProvider value={{ nameModal, showNameModal }}>
            <LoadingProvider value={{ isLoading, setIsLoading }}>
              <div>
                <Routes>
                  {/* <Route path="/signup" element={<Layout page="signup" />} /> */}
                  <Route path="/" element={<Layout page="home" />} />
                  <Route path="/admin" element={<Layout page="admin" />} />
                  <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Layout page="home" />} />
                </Routes>
              </div>
              {isLoading && <Loader />}
              {!isLoading && requestModal && (
                <div className="z-40 fixed inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-50 overflow-y-auto h-full w-full"></div>
              )}
              {!isLoading && requestModal && <RequestModal />}
              {!isLoading && nameModal && (
                <div className="z-40 fixed inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-50 overflow-y-auto h-full w-full"></div>
              )}
              {!isLoading && nameModal && <NameModal />}

              <ToastContainer />
            </LoadingProvider>
          </NameModalProvider>
        </ArticleRequestProvider>
      </RequestModalProvider>
    </UserProfileProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

home page

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import UserProfileContext from "../contexts/UserProfileContext";
import LoadingContext from "../contexts/LoadingContext";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import SideMenu from "./SideMenu";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const Home = () => {
  const { isLoading, setIsLoading } = useContext(LoadingContext);
  const { userProfile, setUserProfile } = useContext(UserProfileContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const {
    loginWithRedirect,
    isAuthenticated,
    isLoading: isLoadingAuth0,
  } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAuthentication = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      if (!isLoadingAuth0 && !isAuthenticated) {
        try {
          await loginWithRedirect();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Authentication error:", error);
        }
      }

      if (userProfile && userProfile.isAdmin) {
        toast.info("Redirect to admin page", {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
        });
        navigate("/admin");
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    handleAuthentication();
  }, [userProfile, isLoadingAuth0, isAuthenticated]);

  if (isAuthenticated && userProfile) {
    return (
      <>
        <SideMenu admin={false} />
        <Dashboard />
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

export default Home;
```

[Auth0 dashboard logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAJst.png)